# External Accessory Framework of iOS to detect other iPhone or iMac

Tags: ios, bluetooth, external-accessory

Is it possible to use the External Accessory Framework of iOS to detect Apple Products like other iPhones, iPods and iMac? Or its just only for the accessory under MFi program? Or can i use CoreBluetooth Framework otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

External Accessory over USB is only for MFi accessories.